# How to change the color of the status bar in the launcher?

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, android-4.4-kitkat, android-launcher

I need to make the status bar black. How can I do this by editing launcher's XML files?

Comment: AFAIK you cannot affect the color of the status bar in the launcher app, unless your app *is* the launcher app.

Comment: My Android version is Kitkat 4.4, which has transparent status bar on home/unlock menu. How can i change the color of that?

Answer (score 0):

You can't effect the color of the status bar with Trebuchet Launcher.
Just something similar like the drawer style since Version Marshmallow +.
Even the mentioned Android 4.4 Kitkat (CM11) is too low for that.

For further accessibility for layout settings you can either download matching versions of Trebuchet or use third party launchers like Action Launcher and Nova Launcher.

Comment: There is no "styles.xml" in Trebuchet.apk

Comment: I suggest to use Android Studio to build your unique Application. I know that Trebuchet isn't that flexible to customize everything. Do you might have screenshot of your work, to help you further?

Comment: Do you know what is Trebuchet? It's Cyanogenmod launcher

Comment: What Version do you use? On version Marshmallow + you can change that in the drawer style. In case you wish to use the paged style layout, you can either download older versions of Trebuchet or use third party launchers like Action Launcher and Nova Launcher.

Comment: Android 4.4 Kitkat (CM11)

Comment: Also, i don't need the other launcher, since I want to change the appearance by changing the APK code, and not through the launcher settings

Comment: I found the solution written solution above. You can't change that. Probably in the future. I think this answer will help others also. Cheers buddy!

Answer (score 0):

```
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">? 
attr/colorPrimaryDark</item>
```

Add this to the style used by the activity. That should change the statusbarcolor.

Remember that you can add any color of your choice.

you can find that from the `theme.xml`. You can know which specific style to edit by checking out the `AndroidManifest` and check the `android:theme.

Comment: I meant launcher's status bar color, and not of ordinary app

Comment: sorry  I did not quite get your question, are you creating a launcher app and want to change it's status bar ? or you want to change the status bar of your app's launcher activity

Comment: I want to change launcher's status bar

Comment: Do you hear me?